# HTML:Automatically update treeview sidebar navigation while scrolling

Tags: navigation, treeview

After visiting [this site](http://www.dbarnes.info/jWizard/#ChangeLog), I like the auto changed sidebar navigate very much.

When you scrolling the page, the side bar tree view is automatically changed.

And I want to know how to achieve this.

Does anyone know it? Or what is the plugin the site are using to do that?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like they are using [Twitter Bootstrap](http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/).

Here is a more direct [link](http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/javascript.html#scrollspy) to the specific Twitter Bootstrap plugin ScrollSpy.

Comment: thanks. The ScrollSpy is almost what it is I think. But what strange is that I dont find bootstrap js file appears in the source. And there's a little difference, the example I give it can show sub title while scrolling.

Comment: I didn't pick up on the subtitles, I'll have a look. It's not so strange that there is no bootstrap.js file, there is an [app.js](http://www.dbarnes.info/jWizard/app.js) which is a concatenated version of a number of js files. In fact when I search through it for "bootstrap" I get a few hits.

Comment: you are right. they intergrated the bootstrap into the app.js. So, clear now, they are suing bootstrap to do that. Thanks!

Comment: To make the answer more complete, there is an `activate` event which is called when a new item becomes activated by ScrollSpy. It looks like they're animating a nested `ul` from `display: none` to `display: block` when the parent `li` is activated. And doing the opposite when deactivating, or when activating another `li`.